# Where does Pico micropython print go with main.py?

Tags: python, uart, pi-pico, micropython, pi-pico-w

If you load a `main.py` file onto the Pico with micropython firmware running, it will run on startup. I can tell that this is working because I observe GPIO outputs changing, etc.

However, I'm not sure where output is going in this mode (e.g. `print`). I've tried connecting to the USB but I just get the usual REPL. I've also tried hooking up a UART probe (specifically, the Raspberry Pi debug probe) to default UART, but I'm not getting output there either (this is the default output for `printf` when using the C SDK, and I can successfully see output from any C firmware that uses `printf` using my debug probe).

Does anyone know where this output is going and how to see it?

I'm also actually using a Pico W but I assume this wouldn't differ from the Pico.

Answer (score 1):

The print goes to USB. If you use Thonny you will see the result.